# How to make mp4 rendering visible on Mac?

Tags: ffmpeg, mp4, animated-gif

Generating mp4 from gif like this:

```
    await new Promise<void>((resolve, reject) => {
        ffmpeg
            .input(`/tmp/input_${name}.gif`)
            .outputOptions([
                '-c:v libx264',
                '-movflags +faststart',
                '-movflags frag_keyframe+empty_moov',
            ])
            .noAudio()
            .output(`/tmp/output_${name}.mp4`)
            .on('end', () => {
                console.log('MP4 video generated')
                resolve()
            })
            .on('error', (e) => {
                console.log(e)
                reject()
            })
            .run()
    })
```

will generate mp4, but can be watch only in Chrome, not in Safari or Quicktime Player.

We tried many other option like this:

```
'-pix_fmt yuv420p',
'-vf "scale=trunc(iw/2)*2:trunc(ih/2)*2"',
```

but it raise an error:

```
Error reinitializing filters!
Failed to inject frame into filter network: Invalid argument
```

[image]

Using this framework in a React / Next.js project: https://github.com/eugeneware/ffmpeg-static

Comment: Add -report and rerun. Share full report.

Comment: **(1)** Does it remove errors if you have only one line for setting all your **movflags**? Example try setting as: `'-movflags faststart+frag_keyframe+empty_moov+separate_moof',` ... **(2)** Check the format of your output video. You can use [Media Info online](https://mediaarea.net/MediaInfoOnline) and for supported playback in most browsers you want video codec to be MPEG's H.264 (aka AVC).